# load bitmap object inside a specific html\asp.net\telerik control

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap, telerik

I have a bitmap object generated dynamically at the code behind, which I would like to load to a certain control within my aspx page. Due to the structure of my application, I'd rather not use an Ihttphandler.

here is an example of my code:

```
WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot ScreenShot = new WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot("NHJ99Q0QTGNG66UUVAGDL4Y1Q");
        WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result Result;
        Result = ScreenShot.CaptureHTML(HTML);
        if (Result == WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result.Captured)
        {
            ScreenShot.ImageWidth = 250;
            ScreenShot.ImageHeight = 300;
            Bitmap pic = ScreenShot.GetImage();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pic.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            //what do I do here ?
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the `RadBinaryImage` control is designed to handle.  It will take your byte[] array and output it directly to the client.  It can even do client side caching if you'd like.  Here's a demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/binaryimage/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

More information and documentation: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radbinaryimage.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it:

```
htmlImg.DataValue = WriteBitmapIntoStream(pic);



private static byte[] WriteBitmapIntoStream(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    stream.Position = 0;
    var data = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    return data;
}
```